# Python - I dont know how to min works in this code

Tags: python, python-2.7, min

My teacher gave me this code:

```
def n_o_c(Q,v):  
    M=[None]*(Q+1)  
    m={}  
    M[0]=0  
    for q in xrange(1,Q+1):  
        M[q]=min(M[q-a]+1 for a in v if q-a>=0)    
    return M[Q],m  

print n_o_c(18,[1,2,5])
```

1st I explain the script, It's a supposed coin machine and I have to know how much coins I need for pay Q quantity having v coins(we have to do less coins as posible IE for 18 3x5 coin 1x2 coin and 1x1 coin)

I dont understand what does that M[q] line, I've tried to print M and the result I had was every number from 1 to 18 how many coins it needs to do that number. 
M=[0,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,3,4,4,3,4,4,5]
q=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18]

Can someone explain me how that min works?

I've already done it (I know its not the good way to solve the exercise but I dont know a better way for). Solved:

```
def n_o_c(Q,v):  
    M=[None]*(Q+1)  
    m={}  
    M[0]=0  
    for q in xrange(1,Q+1):  
        M[q]=min(M[q-a]+1 for a in v if q-a>=0)
    monedas=0
    total=Q
    m=[] # did this to change dictionary to array
    while(monedas<M[Q]):
        for a in v[::-1]:
            if total-a >= 0:
                total = total-a
                monedas = monedas +1
                m.append(a)
                break #I forget this break
    return M[Q],m  

print n_o_c(18,[1,2,5])
```

Comment: what are `(5, [5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1])` in the result?

Comment: solved, i forgot to put break for "for"

Comment: so it was not working? Why did you say you had already done it?

Comment: now its working check it

Comment: I know, but you said in your question it was already solved so that was slightly confusing

Comment: failed copying, I copied it from comp to tablet, im at work computer dosnt have internet

Comment: This is the [greedy change-making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) with an implementation error. The code you show is so broken that I can't fix it without rewriting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function is the easy part:

> Return the smallest item in an iterable

The tricky bit is, what's with that iterable?

```
M[q]=min(M[q-a]+1 for a in v if q-a>=0)
```

That `(M[q-a]+1 for a in v if q-a>=0)` is called a generator expression; more generally, it's a type of comprehension.

Start at [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in the official tutorial to learn how comprehensions in general work, then [Iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) and the following two sections (Generators and Generator Expressions) to learn how generator expressions are different.*

But I can summarize it here, at least enough to get you started.

First, a list comprehension:

```
[M[q-a]+1 for a in v if q-a>=0]
```

What this means is that you want to build a list, exactly as if you'd unrolled it into a loop like this:

```
value = []
for a in v:
    if q-a>=0:
        value.append(M[q-a]+1)
M[q] = min(value)
```

Or, more intuitively, try reading it aloud: a list of every `M[q-a]+1` for each `a` in `v` if `q-a>=0` makes sense as an English sentence, and means exactly the same thing as the Python. (If you have a math background, you might want to think of it in terms of set displays instead, but I'll assume you don't.)

A generator expression does the same thing, except that instead of building a list, it creates the values on demand as you iterate over it. You can think of this as sort of a magic list that doesn't waste memory or time for now. To spell it in Python, just turn the square brackets `[]` into parentheses `()` (which you can leave off in this case, because there are already parentheses from the `min` call). To read it aloud, just leave of the "a list of" part.

---

<sub>* And once you get that, if you want to learn more, take a look at the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module, read [Generator Tricks for System Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/) by David Beazley and google for Greg Ewing's presentations on generators.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have much to learn and read I understand it better but i'm going to read that links you have me too.

*hugs*

Answer (score 0):

Why is m not being used in your teacher's code ?

Here is a solution:
Sort the v list and divide by it by each dimension to get num coins and continue with change remaining.

```
def n_o_c(Q,v):   
   m = {}

   for dimension in sorted(v, reverse= True):
       num_coins = int(Q/dimension)
       ## if Q is not divisible by the dimension, go to the next dimension
       if num_coins != 0:
       ## if Q is divisible, store num_coins in the dictionary
          m[dimension] = num_coins
       ## Get change remaining by modulo function and store it as remaining Q that needs to be broken down
       Q = Q % dimension
   return m

print n_o_c(18,[1,2,5])
```

Should print:
{1: 1, 2: 1, 5: 3}